# In-App billing notificationid unique per state change?

Tags: android, notifications, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In the Android documentation it states;

> notificationId
>
> A unique identifier that is sent with an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast
>   intent. Each notificationId corresponds to a specify message that is
>   waiting to be retrieved on the Google Play server. Your application
>   sends back the notificationId with the GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION
>   message so Google Play can determine which messages you are
>   retrieving.

But is there per unique purchase state change only ONE message therefor ONE unique notificationId.
Or can Google decided to create multiple messages (maybe after failing to respond quickly enough) for the same unique purchase state transition?

In other words:
Is the combination [OrderId,NotificationId] unique per purchase state transition?

Comment: Where do you get the OrderId from?

Answer (score 0):

for each IN_APP_NOTIFY the NotificationId is unique.

Is this what your asking?

Here's a visual overview of In App Purchase it might give you some clarity:

[image: Android In App Purchase Overview]
<sub>(source: [blundellapps.co.uk](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/overview.png))</sub>

[> Bigger Image <](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/overview.png)

Ref: [http://blog.blundell-apps.com/overview-of-android-in-app-billing-flowchart/](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/overview-of-android-in-app-billing-flowchart/)

Comment: I'm missing the 'recall product' in the diagram. And I was wondering if the combination orderid-notificationid was unique per state change, so I can user it as a unique key in de backoffice database to administer which state-transitions were processed.

Comment: @Hubert ah yes refunds aren't included sorry. I still don't see where you are getting orderId, I see what you mean now I wouldn't rely on the notificationId I would do the GetPurchaseInformation service call and use the nonce or your developer payload.